# export excel 2003(xls) file in ruby with date column(cell formatting = date)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to export/create excel sheet 2003 (xls) with date column (cell formating = Date). Please suggest any gem and logic for that.

Comment: i used roo gem but its not working

Comment: rubyXL gem working but its create xlsx file excel 2007 format. But i require xls file with excel 2003 format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem. [Axlsx_rails](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails) helped me. It has various examples.

To format a cell to a Date cell, you have to do the next,

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.styles do |s|
  date = s.add_style(:format_code => "dd/mm/yyyy")
end
```

And then you pass the style you want to the cell, i.e:

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.styles do |s|
  date = s.add_style(:format_code => "dd/mm/yyyy")
  wb.add_worksheet(name: "Example") do |sheet|
     sheet.add_row['Date Column']
     sheet.add_row[Date.today], :style => [date]
  end
end
```

As for the format, you could change the name on save, like so:

```
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xlsx do
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="excel_sheet.xls"'
      end
    end
```